# ASP.Net Web API is returning JSON datetime without time

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, httpresponsemessage

I am facing a strange issue in ASP.Net Web API returning data which return records to display in tabular format, and that data also contains datetime. The problem is when I get data from client, the time part is removed and only date part is retrieved i.e. in "MM/dd/yyyy" format (even log in browser console), while debugging the code, I can see datetime in format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss". I have tried every possibility but could not get it working.

Here is the json data during debug C# code:

```
{"Records": [
  {
    "ProviderName": "Loc 1",
    "FirstName": "A252",
    "LastName": "B252",
    "PhoneNumber": "8000121431",
    "EmailAddress": "ab252@abc.comm",
    "FormName": "Guest",
    "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01 08:50:00 AM",
    "Activate Alert Value": "Yes",
    "Are you experiencing cough?": "No",
    "Are you experiencing fever?": "Yes",
    "Are you sneezing?": "Yes",
    "Alert": "No"
  },
  {
    "ProviderName": "Loc 1",
    "FirstName": "A251",
    "LastName": "B251",
    "PhoneNumber": "8000121430",
    "EmailAddress": "ab251@abc.comm",
    "FormName": "Guest",
    "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01 08:29:00 AM",
    "Activate Alert Value": "Yes",
    "Are you experiencing cough?": "Yes",
    "Are you experiencing fever?": "Yes",
    "Are you sneezing?": "No",
    "Alert": "No"
  },
}
```

And here is the data which I log in browser console.

```
{"Records": [
    {
      "ProviderName": "Loc 1",
      "FirstName": "A252",
      "LastName": "B252",
      "PhoneNumber": "8000121431",
      "EmailAddress": "ab252@abc.comm",
      "FormName": "Guest",
      "CreatedDate": "10/1/2020",
      "Activate Alert Value": "Yes",
      "Are you experiencing cough?": "No",
      "Are you experiencing fever?": "Yes",
      "Are you sneezing?": "Yes",
      "Alert": "No",
      "$$hashKey": "uiGrid-000G"
    },
    {
      "ProviderName": "Loc 1",
      "FirstName": "A251",
      "LastName": "B251",
      "PhoneNumber": "8000121430",
      "EmailAddress": "ab251@abc.comm",
      "FormName": "Guest",
      "CreatedDate": "10/1/2020",
      "Activate Alert Value": "Yes",
      "Are you experiencing cough?": "Yes",
      "Are you experiencing fever?": "Yes",
      "Are you sneezing?": "No",
      "Alert": "No",
      "$$hashKey": "uiGrid-000I"
    },
}
```

Here is the code using NewtonSoft to convert data to Json Object

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(report));
                return Ok(json);
```

The "json" variable contains exact the same 1st json data. It seems that when it returns data through OK(json) it manipulates the datetime.

Please refer to **CreatedDate** in json data for the current issue.

Comment: what do you mean when you say client, is it some front end application or some tool such as postman/swagger?

Comment: It is browser. I have tested it on postman and it is fine there, the full datetime is showing there. Not sure why this is showing problem on browser. I think this can be due to AngularJS Web API which is somewhere processing the data.

Comment: yes, much clearer now. There no issue with the webApi. it how you are consuming it in your client application. I see you have mentioned AngularJs. Please share your code where you are consuming it.